# XSLT failing on Access 2013

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, ms-access-2013

We have been employing an XSLT template to transform an XML file into another XML file for importing into an Access 2003 table, but since moving to Access 2013 this no longer works.

Here is the template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:nr1="urn:com.axonglobal.mcc.academy.payments.ap.inbound" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />


<xsl:template match="/">

<root>

  <xsl:apply-templates />

</root>

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="nr1:mt_generic_ap_source_file_xml/fileheader">

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="nr1:mt_generic_ap_source_file_xml/filetrailer">

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="nr1:mt_generic_ap_source_file_xml/invoiceheader[ paymentmethod = 'C' ] ">

</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="nr1:mt_generic_ap_source_file_xml/invoiceheader[ paymentmethod = 'B' ] ">


  <xsl:variable name="paytype" select="substring(headertext,1,2)" />


  <tblBACS_Payments>

  <creditor_id>

    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(headertext,'|')" />

  </creditor_id>

  <cheque_num>

    <xsl:value-of select="vendorname2" />

  </cheque_num>

  <posting_date>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(postingdate,1,4),'-',substring(postingdate,5,2),'-',substring(postingdate,7,2))" />

  </posting_date>

  <paymenttype>

    <xsl:value-of select="document('sappaycats.xml')/paycategories/category[@id = $paytype]/@description" />

  </paymenttype>

  <invoicetotal>

    <xsl:value-of select="invoicetotal" />

  </invoicetotal>



  <xsl:for-each select="headerremittance [textid = 'PA'] ">

    <payee_name>

      <xsl:value-of select="text[1]" />

    </payee_name>

  </xsl:for-each>



  <sortcode>

    <xsl:value-of select="bankkey" />

  </sortcode>

  <bankaccount>

    <xsl:value-of select="bankaccount" />

  </bankaccount>

  <bankref>

    <xsl:value-of select="buildingsocietyref" />

  </bankref>


  </tblBACS_Payments>



</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is a sample of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nr1:mt_generic_ap_source_file_xml xmlns:nr1="xxx">
<fileheader>
    <datatype>H0</datatype>
    <sourcesystem>System</sourcesystem>
    <interfaceid>0130</interfaceid>
    <date>20161219</date>
    <filename>File</filename>
    <runnumber>20160051</runnumber>
</fileheader>
<invoiceheader>
    <datatype>H1</datatype>
    <invoicereference>1486322</invoicereference>
    <vendorid>xxx</vendorid>
    <legacyvendorid/>
    <invoicetotal>7.34</invoicetotal>
    <currencycode>GBP</currencycode>
    <discount/>
    <paymentterm/>
    <paymentmethod>C</paymentmethod>
    <paymentsupplement/>
    <invoicedate>20161226</invoicedate>
    <postingdate>20161226</postingdate>
    <businessarea/>
    <headertext>03|91238</headertext>
    <contactname/>
    <contactnumber/>
    <vendorname1>xxxx</vendorname1>
    <vendorname2>1486322</vendorname2>
    <vendorname3/>
    <vendorname4/>
    <houseandstreet>xxxx</houseandstreet>
    <city>xxx</city>
    <postcode>M12 3AB:</postcode>
    <pobox/>
    <poboxpostcode/>
    <country>GB</country>
    <faxnumber/>
    <headerremittance>
        <datatype>R1</datatype>
        <textid>MA</textid>
        <text>.....</text>
        <text>XYZ</text>
        <text>XYZ</text>
        <text>XYZ</text>
        <text>XYZ</text>
    </headerremittance>
    <headerremittance>
        <datatype>R1</datatype>
        <textid>PA</textid>
        <text>xxxxx</text>
    </headerremittance>
    <invoiceitem>
        <datatype>D2</datatype>
        <itemnumber>0000000001</itemnumber>
        <amount>7.34</amount>
        <taxamount/>
        <taxcode>V3</taxcode>
        <costcentre>105417</costcentre>
        <glcode>462000</glcode>
        <companycode>1000</companycode>
        <businessarea/>
        <itemtext/>
    </invoiceitem>
</invoiceheader>
</nr1:mt_generic_ap_source_file_xml>
```

I am getting an error in Access 'specified transform failed to successfully transform your data', but it worked OK in Access 2003?

Any ideas?

Comment: I have never used XSLT with Access but since XSLT 1.0 was released in 1999 most processors like `XslCompiledTransform` or MSXML 6 by default have been changed to disallow the use of e.g. `document('sappaycats.xml')`, that is the use of the `document` function by default for security reasons and need to explicitly enable that. So you might want to check whether Access offers any settings to allow the use of `document` in XSLT stylesheets it executes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen ... MS Access like all Office softwares can interface with [MSXML 3/6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204(v=vs.85).aspx) library as you point out, available as VBA reference or COM object. And `document()` by default is turned off but can be allowed.

Comment: @BenHamilton - please show the code to process the XSLT. We need to know how you are running it. Recall XSLT is a special-purpose language and actually just an XML file. Some general-purpose language/executable/client must run it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thank you, I may have to implement this as a VBA module within access using older library, or check the settings in Access 2013. We are currently just going to External Data - Import XML, and then selecting the transform. 

I had completely forgotten about the sappaycats.xml file - it is a seperate file stores in the same folder as the .xsl file. Perhaps there's a way of including this info in the .xsl.

Comment: If you use VBA and MSXML 6 to implement the transformation then you simply need to make sure you set https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762664(v=vs.85).aspx `AllowDocumentFunction` to true, I don't think there is a need to use an older library. As for using the Import XML feature, I would hope that it allows you to configure MSXML to set such properties if needed but I am not familiar with Access, hopefully someone else can help with that.